# helm template escaped values for Grafana charts

Tags: kubernetes-helm, grafana

wise SOers.  It turns out Grafana dashboard json files use the same `{{ }}` to do variable substitution as helm does.  I have a grafana chart that is laden with these `{{ }}` to a disagreeable degree.

When I want to put that chart into a template, like so:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: super-dashboard
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
    grafana_dashboard: "1"
data:
  super-dashboard.json: |-
{{ .Files.Get "super-dashboard.json"  | indent 4 }
```

It works great as long as the `super-dashboard.json` doesn't have any thing in it like:

`"legendFormat": "{{status}} Status",`.

Unfortunately, our dashboard does have such a woeful line.  When I run helm, I get:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: parse error at (templates/dashboards/super-dashboard.json:282): function "status" not defined
```

Naturally, it's looking for some method `status` which does not exist in the helm template language and fails thusly.  If only I could ignore parsing of that pestering file. Oh, ye wise masters of the Internet, have you any sage advice for the humble seeker of your collective wisdom?

Comment: How are you installing the chart?  The `.Files.Get` path you should shouldn't cause the included file to be reinterpreted by the templating engine; you would need to explicitly call [`tpl`](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function) for that.  Does `helm template` work on the chart, and if so, does the produced YAML look more or less correct around this block?

Comment: I'm installing the chart with: `helm upgrade --install mychart -f ./mychart/values.yaml ./mychart` The json file is in the same directory as the template.  (`./mychart/template/`)

Comment: there is some discussion here:  https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2798  I like the idea that ntfrnzn has but if I include any of these files in the relative directory I get the error.  If I put them outside the directory they don't get picked up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was my `super-dashboard.json` file was in the same directories as the templates and helm tried to templatize it.  The solution is to have a directory structure like:

```
mychart/
  templates/
    super-dashboard.yaml
  files/
    super-dashboard.json
```

Then the `yaml` file has:

```
{{ .Files.Get "files/super-dashboard.json" | indent 4 }}
```

I thought you had to put the files in the same directory but it just has to be at the root of the chart.